# Two asterisks in filename **/*

Tags: linux, git

What does a file name like `some_directory/**/*` mean? It's a part of git's .gitignore file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it should ignore any files under all directories of `some_directory`.

So:

- files directly within `some_directory` aren't ignored
- files under directories under `some_directory` (second level) are ignored.